# Web API 2 - Uso de ReasonPhrase em tratamento de exceções

Tags: c#, exceção, asp.net-web-api, iis

```
var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    ReasonPhrase = "Nenhum produto encontrado"
};

throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
```

Esse código deveria retornar

> 404 Nenhum produto encontrado

Mas por algum motivo não está funcionando. Alguma ideia? Estou usando Visual Studio 2013 e IIS Express.

#### Print de exemplo (ignorem a URL e o uso de HEAD, foi apenas para ilustrar)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que é a sua interface de teste que não lê a `ReasonPhrase`. Já tentou testar usando uma requisição Ajax assim? http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/handling-exceptions-in-asp.net-web-api.htm

Comment: Isso aí mesmo @CiganoMorrisonMendez...

Comment: Nestas situações o [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com/) é o teu maior amigo.

Comment: @PauloMorgado eu desconfiei que fosse algo do tipo, e agora que confirmei passei a usar ele...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, aparentemente a dica dada pelo [Cigano Morrison Mendez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2999/cigano-morrison-mendez) está correta, fiz um pequeno teste usando o JS abaixo:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'api/teste/?id=1',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.CustomerID + " - " + result.CompanyName);
    },
    error: function (err, type, httpStatus) {
        alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText + " - " + httpStatus);
    }
});
```

E aí deu certo, exibiu a ReasonPhrase e o conteúdo da resposta. Vou passar a usar o [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) para evitar esse tipo de coisa!